# How to pass OnClickListener from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to pass an OnClickListener object from activity to a Fragment.
I can't pass argument to Fragment constructor, so i want to do something like:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putCustomObject(new OnClickListener(){...});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a method to the fragment:

```
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener) { mListener = listener;}
```

Call Fragment's method:

```
mFragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { /* YOUR CODE HERE */ });
```

Comment: If there is any configuration changes (like screen rotation), the listener will be cleared

Comment: @josefatef Interfaces like OnClickListener(s) cannot be Parcelled or Serialized, so there isn't any other way to pass them to a Fragment. Activity/other_fragment, when the Configuration changes, has to re-set it again to this other Fragment. BTW even this Fragment instance is lost, so the new one has to receive again the new (but different instance) OnClickListener. (PS: suggesting to hold a reference to that listener in a ViewModel is not the right way to do things and avoid mem leaks)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to create an `interface` with a method `onClick()` and set the callback from the `Activity` to the `Fragment`.

Interface

```
public interface FragmentClickListener
{
    void onClick();
}
```

Create a variable and method in Fragment class to receive the FragmentClickListener:

```
private FragmentClickListener listener;

public void setOnClickListener(FragmentClickListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Then in some method of your Fragment class you can call the listener like this:

```
void someMethod()
{
    if(listener != null) {
        listener.onClick();
    }
}
```

In your Activity class define the call back like this:

```
fragment.setOnClickListener(new FragmentClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
            //do something here
    }
});
```